# Paypal Payment Data Transfer (PDT)

Tags: php, paypal

When a user logs into the site they are shown all their unpaid invoices. I have added a Paypal button, where the user can pay the invoice.

Below is my button

```
   <td><form action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>
    <input type='hidden' name='business' value='XX@XXXX.co.uk'>
    <input type='hidden' name='lc' value='UK'>
    <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Message'>
    <input type='hidden' name='button_subtype' value='Services'>
    <input type='hidden' name='no_note' value='0'>
    <input type='hidden' name='cn' value='This payment is for Invoice V$id'>
    <input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
    <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='$amount'>
    <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='GBP'>
    <input type='hidden' name='bn' value='PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted'>
    <input type='submit' value='Pay Invoice'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://XXX.co.uk/XX/XX/client-area/paypal_pdt.php'> 
    </form> </td>
```

The payment is working fine, however I need the transaction details to post back to the payment complete page. I have looked at numerous examples and guides however I just cannot seem to get the data to return.

Here is my current script on my return page

```
    <?php

$pp_hostname = "ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com"; // Change to www.sandbox.paypal.com to test against sandbox


// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';

$tx_token = $_GET['tx'];
$auth_token = "KgJfumYNDMtdEneJYjzTJL_kziYsJGQLd0Z3VC0bzsMM54LNKdCZ3-8s378";
$req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$pp_hostname/cgi-bin/webscr");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
//set cacert.pem verisign certificate path in curl using 'CURLOPT_CAINFO' field here,
//if your server does not bundled with default verisign certificates.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: $pp_hostname"));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if(!$res){
    //HTTP ERROR
}else{
     // parse the data
    $lines = explode("\n", $res);
    $keyarray = array();
    if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0) {
        for ($i=1; $i<count($lines);$i++){
        list($key,$val) = explode("=", $lines[$i]);
        $keyarray[urldecode($key)] = urldecode($val);
    }
    // check the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment
    $firstname = $keyarray['first_name'];
    $lastname = $keyarray['last_name'];
    $itemname = $keyarray['item_name'];
    $amount = $keyarray['payment_gross'];

    echo ("<p><h3>Thank you for your purchase!</h3></p>");

    echo ("<b>Payment Details</b><br>\n");
    echo ("<li>Name: $firstname $lastname</li>\n");
    echo ("<li>Item: $itemname</li>\n");
    echo ("<li>Amount: $amount</li>\n");
    echo ("");
    }
    else if (strcmp ($lines[0], "FAIL") == 0) {
        // log for manual investigation
    }
}

?>

<?php echo
"
Payment Name $firstname $lastname   <br />
Item Name $itemname  <br />
Amount $amount <br /><br />  ";?>


Your transaction has been completed, and a receipt for your purchase has been emailed to you.<br> You may log into your account at <a href='https://www.paypal.com'>www.paypal.com</a> to view details of this transaction.<br>
```

The success page isnt showing the TX information either? Its just  www.XXX.co.uk/XX/XX/client-area/paid.php

No data seems to be returning to the page. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have given a lot of good info, but the nature of the failure remains unclear. Are you getting the tx= parameter back? You say that the page is not displaying it, but is the TX in the URL from PayPal (should be visible in the browser)? Is your PHP getting it (e.g. can you log it)? If not, have you gone throught the account setup at the bottom of this page (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/)? If you have a transaction ID, what is the PayPal response? What if you just curl PayPal with the transaction ID directly?

Comment: Also: I am guessing from the comment in the code that the "ssl://" in the PayPal URL is some sort of intentional munge, and is edited out of the script before running it?